# How to remove unwanted characters from Guzzlehttp json reposnce

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, guzzle

Hi I am new to Laravel and have tried several turtorials on Goutte on Guzzelhttp but I am still unable to figure out how to remove 3 unwanted charactures from the begining of the json responce as shown here using curl and json_decode.

```
$url = "URL to atom feed";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

// using CURL to get our results
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $pass);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// decoding our results into an associative array
// doing a substring as there are 3 weird characters being passed back from IIS in front of the string
$data = json_decode(substr($output, 3, strlen($output)), true);

// grabbing our results object
$list = $data['$resources'];
```

I have in my ScrapeController,

```
<?php

// app/controllers/ScrapeController.php
class ScrapeController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex() {
        echo "Scrape index page.";
    }

    public function getNode($node) {
        echo "Scraped page $node";
    }

    public function getPages() {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->get('URL to atom feed', ['auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']]);
        echo $res->getStatusCode();
        // "200"
       // echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
        // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
       echo $res->getBody();
        // {"type":"User"...'
```

this is what I have tried `$res->getBody(substr($res, 3, strlen($res));`without any luck I am unable to find any answers to this problem on guzzle documents page save to say any custom json_decode option should be preformed in the getBody() option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
$body = substr($res->getBody(), 3)
```

instead of

```
$body = $res->getBody(substr($res, 3, strlen($res))
```

Comment: hi jedrzej.kurylo is there any documentation on parameters that can be used within guzzlehttp?

Comment: I don't know. For sure there must be documentation on guzzlehttp github. But this fix has nothing to do with guzzle, it is just an operation on strings

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this piece of code on github by Colin Viebrock,

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client('http://example.com');

$client->addSubscriber( new Cviebrock\Guzzle\Plugin\StripBom\StripBomPlugin() );

$request = $client->get('some/request');

$response = $client->send($request);

$data = $response->json();
```

works a treat in laravel hope this helps anyone how gets "Unable to parse response body into JSON: 4" using Guzzle.